# Symfony 2.1 - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I am getting this error when trying to open a route in Symfony 2.1

I realy have no idea where to check that. There is nothing on the internet.

Thank you very much for your help:

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_wdt" as such route does not exist.") in "@WebProfiler/Profiler/toolbar_js.html.twig" at line 15." at /home/milos/workspace/merrin3.0/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php line 280

Comment: please check my answer and respond if it helped :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This Exception is thrown in the **dev** environment if the **profiler** is enabled but it's routing configuration is missing.

```
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_wdt" as such route does not exist.
```

Please check that your app/config/routing_dev.yml contains the following lines:

```
# app/config/routing_dev.yml

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. The problem was that I deleted the routing_dev.yml and I change it the config_dev.yml to point to _router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }_

Answer (score 0):

Rename folder vendor or delete (project backup), use composer install again.(Server Windows)(Symfony 2.3.35)